# Trying to count all symbols and numbers in a word file. Program outputs symbols but not how many times they appear

Tags: vb.net, basic

(Visual Basic)

This is the word file I'm reading from:

```
`#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

Download link: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/465979/words.txt

I am trying to find all the different characters and symbols inside the word files, and then count them, and output them as a frequency. For example ("The symbol '#' appears (8) times"), ("The number(0) appears (3) times") etc.

I am using a 2 dimensional array and storing the symbols in the first column and the amount of times they appear in the second.

This is my current code:

```
Sub Main() 
    Dim UncodedWords(10) As String
    Dim Symcheck(19, 3) As String
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    Symcheck(0, 0) = ("+")
    Symcheck(0, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(1, 0) = ("/")
    Symcheck(1, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(2, 0) = ("’")
    Symcheck(2, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(3, 0) = ("&")
    Symcheck(3, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(4, 0) = (":")
    Symcheck(4, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(5, 0) = ("$")
    Symcheck(5, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(6, 0) = ("-")
    Symcheck(6, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(7, 0) = ("!")
    Symcheck(7, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(8, 0) = (".")
    Symcheck(8, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(9, 0) = ("""")
    Symcheck(9, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(10, 0) = ("0")
    Symcheck(10, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(11, 0) = ("1")
    Symcheck(11, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(12, 0) = ("2")
    Symcheck(12, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(13, 0) = ("3")
    Symcheck(13, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(14, 0) = ("4")
    Symcheck(14, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(15, 0) = ("5")
    Symcheck(15, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(16, 0) = ("6")
    Symcheck(16, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(17, 0) = ("7")
    Symcheck(17, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(18, 0) = ("8")
    Symcheck(18, 1) = ("0")
    Symcheck(19, 0) = ("9")
    Symcheck(19, 1) = ("0")
    Dim Newtext(10) As String
    Dim FileLoc As String = "C:\Users\Downloads\words.txt" 
    Dim StringReader As New StreamReader(FileLoc, FileMode.Open)
    For Counter = 0 To 9  ' for each line in the file
        UncodedWords(Counter) = StringReader.ReadLine
    Next

    For Counter = 0 To 9 ' for each word in the file
        For length = 1 To Len(UncodedWords(Counter)) - 1 
            For Counter2 = 0 To 19 ' for each symbol in symcheck
                If UncodedWords(Counter).Contains(Symcheck(Counter2, 0)) Then 
                    X += 1
                Else

                End If
                WriteLine(Symcheck(Counter2, 0))
                WriteLine(Symcheck(Counter2, X))
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

One simple, though not necessarily efficient, method is to begin with an empty Symcheck. Then check each character in the input string. If you've encountered the character before (i.e., if it's in Symcheck; use IndexOf), increment its counter. Otherwise, add it to Symcheck with zero count.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a hash map (hash table) is used for.
Loop through each character in the txt file, and perform a check. If the key exists in the hash map, then increment that keys value, else add the key with a value of 0.

Psuedocode:

```
For each letter in txtFile
    If (HashMap.KeyExists(letter)) then
        HashMap(letter).Value += 1
    Else
        HashMap.Add(letter, 0)
    End If    
Next
```